# Get data from server before loading next script

Tags: javascript

I have a few web pages that load Javascript files with the same basic structure.

`page.html`

```html
<script src="js/common.js"></script>
<script src="js/page_specific.js"></script>
```

I now want to make a change to my pages to load some data from a backend server before running the `page_specific.js`.

The way I have done this so far is to remove the `page_specific.js` script tag from the HTML, create a Promise in the `common.js` that resolves once it has the data from the server. Then in the `page.html` I load the `page_specific.js` once the Promise is resolved:

```js
// Load the options first (in common.js) and then load page specific js.
loadOptions.then(() => {
    var js = document.createElement("script");
    js.onload = () => {
        page_specific.Init();
    }
    js.src = "js/page_specific.js";
    document.body.appendChild(js);
});
```

This works but it, of course, means I have to change each of my pages (remove the script tag and add JS to load it dynamically later as per above).

Is there a way to achieve something similar that doesn't require changing every page (e.g. within `common.js`)? If not, is there any downside to the above method?

ETA: there is also a page specific function that is called from the HTML (different names). I've added the `onload` in code above.

Comment: You could wrap everything you are doing in page_specific.js into a function, and then have your common.js call that function, once it has fetched the data.

Comment: Change the common to load another js file and empty page_specific or just grep your pages and remove `<script src="js/page_specific.js"></script>`

Comment: @mplungjan I am not sure I understand. Do you mean that common should load the page_specific.js? How does common know which JS file to load as each is different (page specific)?

Comment: From the url?,,,